# How does one contact an editor?

Tags: discussion, editing

I've noticed some users with editing privileges make a lot of edits that are either unnecessary or go beyond what is outlined in the [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit). (Sometimes I think it wouldn't hurt to either raise the bar higher than 2,000 Reputation or require at least one other high-rep user to approve a change.)

They are edits that don't objectively improve the answer and instead conform an answer to one's personal stylistic preferences. An example would be changing an ampersand to the word, "and." Another example may be changing a suggested word in italics to bold.

I am not talking about stylistic edits that are done in addition to fixing a typo, embedding a quote in a quote box, or some other valid reason to edit. I am referring to lone trivial edits.

Because they have not been informed that these edits are unproductive, these edits may proliferate.

- Stack Exchange does not have a personal messaging system.
- If I simply write the @ sign, as in @User123, will the user be notified? I think the answer is "No."
- If I comment on the edited question or answer, the editor won't be notified because the editor is not the original author.

So, if I wanted to start a dialogue with a user about their editing MO, or get their attention directly via notification, is there a way to do so?

Comment: As an aside, the question you link to about italics is about *use-mention,* not emphasis. Italics are preferred for "word as a word"; and for that reason I for one prefer to use bold for emphasis.

Comment: Good to know. So is it worth editing a post only to change a word from italics to bold?

Comment: You can communicate with an "editor" in two ways, the first and probably the easiest is using the @ I've tried it in the past and the user is notified. But whether they reply is up to them. Another way is chat, but some users may be hesitant to enter into such an arena, it's worth noting that you can open a separate room but no conversation is private. A feature which I personally disagree with for variant reasons.

Comment: That user has [many questionable edits](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/50044/nvz?tab=activity&sort=revisions). But not many obviously wrong ones. They have enough rep that they no longer get rep from suggested edits, so they're most likely just trying to help.

Comment: @curiousdannii I have no doubt the user is trying to help. That doesn't mean the user *is* helping, however.

Comment: @Mari-LouA But the @ notification only works if the person being notified posted a comment, an answer, or was the OP of the question. In my case, as the person being notified merely made an edit, if I posted "@NVZ" anywhere on that thread, anywhere in this thread, or in a chatroom, NVZ will not be notified.

Comment: You have to post your comment in the answer or question that was edited by the user. The identity of the editor is aleays on display until a new edit replaces the previous one. If the user visits chat, why can't he or she be' notified?

Comment: @Mari-LouA But the editor would not receive a notification if I commented on an answer he/she edited, correct?

Comment: As i said earler, it's up to the editor if they reply or not. It doesn't mean they were not notified.

Comment: About five minutes ago, I  commented in a [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage) and used the @ sign to notify you. You never received a notification. Therefore, you will never know about my post. What I am trying to say is this: If I comment on a question or answer, the only way the editor will know about my post and ever see my post is if the editor happens to stumble upon it on accident, which isn't likely. My goal is to communicate with the editor and understand why the edit was made—but I guess there is no way to do this?

Comment: I never visit chat, but if you look for a post which I have edited, the notification should work. Try a really old post where I haven't left a comment though (this might be the trickier part!). Recently I notified a user about his edit, he replied confirming he had been pinged, either he was lying or he actually was pinged.

Comment: Upon conducting some tests with @Mari-LouA, we know definitively that the editor **is** in fact notified if you use the @ tag—even if the user never provided a comment or an answer. So, it seems, in light of the chatroom's non-notification, mentioning the user in a comment on the edited post is the best route!

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's worth noting that the @ mentions do not work sitewide and require that the user at least made an edit. Twenty minutes ago, I mentioned your username in a [comment in a thread with none of your answers, comments, or edits](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/294715/meaning-of-light-of-the-view-in-the-question-makes-light-of-the-view-presente/294717#294717). You did not receive a notification, correct?

Comment: I checked several of these "questionable" edits, and most of them fall into a few general categories: using bold for emphasis, [putting quotes in quote boxes](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/177604/revisions), [fixing typos](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/308144/revisions), [embedding hyperlinks](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/307980/revisions), [fixing capitalizations](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/275231/revisions). All told, they make the overall site look more professional and polished. This all looks like helpful housekeeping to me.

Comment: Disclaimer: If such edits are indeed "unhelpful," then I may be one of the worst "repeat offenders."

Comment: @J.R. I don't think these actions (inserting quote boxes, correcting typos, hyperlinks, or capitalizations) are unhelpful. I think editing a post only to change an italicized word to bold is unhelpful.

Comment: @Kyle - I think the body of work as a whole is productive, helpful, and improves the site. And I wouldn't characterize an italics-to-bold conversion as "unhelpful," just maybe as more trivial than some of the other edits.

Comment: Kyle, @Mari-LouA This [faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) on the main Meta explains who is notified. In particular it is notified "Any user who has edited the post (does not include pending or rejected edit suggestions)".

Comment: You can ping me in the chat room with @Rathony as I visited the chat room before. However, you can never ping a user who has never visited a chat room. Can you ping me when you are in the chat room? I'd like to have a few words with you.

Comment: The main thrust of this question: How do I contact an editor? seems to be obscured by the focus on a particular edit and whether it was helpful or not.

Comment: *Gratuitous* means "done without good reason". And by discussing in particular about my edits, you imply mine are gratuitous? I intended to help speed-readers identify the single-word-answers out of the blocks of texts, which IMO is a good reason.

Comment: @NVZ I just used that case as an example. I view edits like that as gratuitous not because it's a bad idea, but because it's a preference; you would be editing heaps of posts daily if you felt inclined to bold the suggested word in every answer. This would result in a lot of unsubstantial edits. From the [EL&U Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit): "**Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged.**" (The bold is the Help Center's emphasis, not mine!)

Comment: @Kyle Trivial edits are discouraged, I'm aware. Even the Help Centre used bold for emphasis, which made that sentence easier to notice. My edits were meant to make certain words or phrases easier to notice. But I do agree that imposing my style onto others' answers are bad and I've stopped it since. You should also know that discussing about a particular user on meta is [**not nice**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: @NVZ I edited the question to remove the distraction of the particular edit.

Comment: @Kyle Although you've made my answer obsolete, your effort to remove focus from me is good. Still, this is a mix of questions: 1. How may I contact an editor? 2. What defines a helpful edit? 3. What is the best method to highlight or emphasise certain words or phrases? The answers are: 1. Already answered. 2. See Help Centre. 3. Debatable.

Answer (score 8):

Massimo Ortolano posted this link in the comments, which provides details about how the @replies operate:

[*How do comment @replies work?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

The best practice is to comment on the edited post and use the @ reply to ping the editor, who will be pinged even if the editor has not left any comments or answers.

Answer (score 5):

Chanced upon this meta now. Surprised to see that it mentions me. Here's the thing. Mostly,

## I'm a speed reader.

Otherwise,
I have a mind like a sieve.

When there are multiple answers to a question, each with many suggested words and lengthy explanation, I can't help but fail to peruse them.

Big or bold words catch my attention while *italics* don't. So, in my own posts I follow a style accordingly, a style where the **suggested words are highlighted** and the **explanation is hidden** in plain sight. (*see* [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/302254/50044), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/323472/50044), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/319928/50044), [4](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/304683/50044), [5](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/322106/50044), [6](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/315305/50044), [7](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/318165/50044), [8](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/321322/50044), [9](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/322001/50044))

Back then, my edits on others' posts were aimed at helping those other speed-readers, knowing that the respective owners can simply roll back my edits if they wanted to.

It's my bad when I edit others' posts to reflect my style. I have made my fair share of mistakes. Forgive the old me. Trust the new me because I've learnt tons over these months.

Comment: It's odd to see a downvote on an apology. What gives?

Comment: After the question got edited, my answer has become obsolete. But I welcome the edit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that too many users are 'editing' simply to bring somebody else's post into line with their own personal preferences. In short, they are editing for style rather than content. I too have had posts 'edited' for petty stuff like changing italics to bold, or changing the way I post a link, and to be totally honest with me it irritates the hell out of me! Sure, as Rathony says, it can be rolled back but it still leaves a bad feeling against the petty editor.

What is needed is some guidelines for editing, as generally speaking editors (meaning professionals) edit out errors, reformat to a house style if such a thing exists, but actively avoid editing for their own preferences. While an editor may prefer to see *December 20th*, they will not 'correct' *20th December* unless there is a house style guide saying "dates should be written as December 20th" I am sure the petty editors in ELU think they are being helpful, so they need educating and an editing guide/style guide would be helpful in that. I agree with Kyle's grievance, butI don't agree that contacting the petty editor is a good way to do it - that looks like a recipe for an argument to me. A set of guidelines is less personal.

Alternatives... raise the rep required for editing. Or do the reverse - high rep brings immunity to editing, except maybe for editing by mods.